# Rails: Would this go in a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I've currently got this in my view file:

```
<%= "<em>(#{package.to_company})</em>" unless package.to_company.blank? %>
```

Is my understanding correct that I should move that to a helper?

ie.

```
def package_company(package)
  "<em>(#{package.to_company})</em>" unless package.to_company.blank?
end
```

I ask because I've got a few dozen `unless` statements in this specific view based on if a user submits specific data or not. Seemed overkill to create a few dozen helper methods for just single `unless` statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create this helper if you'are going to re-use this exact chunk of code many times (and stay DRY)… if you're going to use it once, you don't need an helper…